# For all real $x$ the expression$ \frac{x^2-2x+4}{x^2+2x+4}$ lies between $\frac 13$ and $3$.

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

> The values between which the expression $$\frac{9.3^{2x}+6.3^x+4}{9.3^{2x}-6.3^x+4}$$ is

A solution I saw says that the expression can be written as 
$$\frac{(3.3^x)^2+2(3.3^x)+4}{(3.3^x)^2-2.(3.3^x)+4}$$ which is analogous to the previous expression and hence would have the same interval. Why are they analogous? Clearly it has $x$ as a power, so something has to change right? Why are they the same?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845952/range-of-the-function-fx-fracx214x9x22x3-where-x-in-mathbb

Comment: Technically, it is only equivalent to $\frac{x^2+2x+4}{x^2-2x+4}$ for $x>0,$ not all real $x.$

Comment: Let $3.3^x=t$ and convert the equation accordingly.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar both equations have the same coefficients, so there range would be equal, I get it. But I still feel that $x$ being in $ t$ has to change something.

Comment: @Aditya it does change something. $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} 3.3^x = 0, \lim_{x \to \infty} 3.3^x = \infty$$ So, range of the two equations are not completely equal. The range of your original equation is only equivalent to the range of the modified equation where $t>0$, just as Thomas Andrews says above.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't see what you mean. Both are rational functions in $3^x,$ which is defined for all $x.$ Both expressions fail to be defined only when (if ever) their denominators vanish.

Comment: So, $3.3^x$ can never take a negative value, but $t$ can take negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{9.3^{2x}+6.3^x+4}{9.3^{2x}-6.3^x+4}$$

$$\frac{(3)^2(3^x)^2+2(3)(3^x)+4}{(3)^2(3^x)^2-2(3)(3^x)+4}$$

$$\frac{(3.3^x)^2+2(3.3^x)+4}{(3.3^x)^2-2(3.3^x)+4}$$

$$\frac{(z)^2+2(z)+4}{(z)^2-2(z)+4}$$