# If $x\in R$, then $\frac{x^2+2x+a}{x^2+4x+3a}$ can take all real values for what range of $a$

Tags: functions

I am well aware of the method to solve this question. It’s quite tedious, but it can be done. The answer is $a\in (0,1)$

Now, I was experimenting with a few terms, and I figured that the denominator can never be equal to zero

$$x^2+4x+3a\not =0$$
So the discriminant will be negative. 
$$16-12a<0$$
$$12a>16$$
$$a>\frac 43$$

Which is a direct contradiction to the answer. Pleas explain this

Also, is there a shorter way to solve this? I remember this question coming in an exam, and I solved it in like half a minute using various tricks, but I just can’t remember how to do it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845952/range-of-the-function-fx-fracx214x9x22x3-where-x-in-mathbb

Comment: Solve $$y=\frac{x^2+2x+a}{x^2+4x+3a}$$ for $x$ to get $$x=\frac{\pm\sqrt{-3 a y^2+4 a y-a+4 y^2-4 y+1}-2 y+1}{y-1}$$ (or $x=-a$ if $y=1$) so we must have $$-3 a y^2+4 a y-a+4 y^2-4 y+1\geq0$$ for all $y$

Comment: There is error in reasoning. You indeed need denominator going to zero, how else can this function ever go to infinity?

Comment: You need to show why $a\notin(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: @AndrewChin I don’t understand

Comment: @jeea it sounds reasonable, but isn’t a denominator being zero straight up invalid?

Comment: @Aditya That is not what we are concerned about right, on the poles the function will be, undefined. But we do have domain around the poles, so that function can attain arbirtrarily large values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve $$y=\frac{x^2+2x+a}{x^2+4x+3a}$$ for $x$ to get $$x=\frac{\pm\sqrt{(4-3 a) y^2+(4 a-4) y-a+1}-2 y+1}{y-1}$$ (or $x=-a$ if $y=1$) so we must have $$(4-3 a) y^2+(4 a-4) y-a+1\geq0$$ for all $y$.

Now let $f(a,y)=(4-3 a) y^2+(4 a-4) y-a+1$. It is clear that $f(a, \cdot)$ is bounded from below if and only if $a<\frac43$. In that case, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,y)=a (4 - 6 y) + 8 y-4$$

which is $0$ iff $y=\frac{2 (a-1)}{3 a-4}$. It is easy to check that this is a minimum and $$f\left(\frac{2 (a-1)}{3 a-4}\right)=\frac{(a-1) a}{3 a-4}.$$

Since this must always be $\geq0$ and we know $a<\frac43$, we can conclude immediately that $0\geq a\geq 1$ must be true. 
If $a=0$ or $a=1$, then $y=\frac12$ or $y=0,1$ can not be attained respectively so we need to discard them.

Comment: The answer should be $0<a<1$; when $a=0$, $y$ cannot be $1/2$ or $1$, and when $a=1$, $y$ cannot be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @AndrewChin Thanks, fixed